# How to move a single plot behind the grid?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to make an axis in tikz with multiple plots and a grid, where one of the plots is plotted behind the grid. In particular, I want to make a colored area to mark a region for other plots, but I want the grid to be on top of it. However, the grid should still be behind the other plots. I can't figure how it's done. I've read in the pgfplots manual that `axis on top` can be used to move *all* plots behind the grid, but this is not what I need.

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{0.8,1,0.8}%

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=8cm,
height=4cm,
xmajorgrids,
ymajorgrids,
% axis on top, % <-- uncomment to move all plots behind grid
]

% this should be behind the grid:
\addplot[fill=mycolor,draw=none,forget plot]
table[row sep=crcr]{
x y\\
0 -1 \\
1 -2 \\
1 1 \\
0 1 \\
};

% these should be in front of the grid
\addplot [color=black, line width=3pt]
table[row sep=crcr]{
0 0\\
.4 2\\
.6 1\\
1 1\\
};

\addplot [color=red, line width=3pt]
table[row sep=crcr]{
0 -1\\
.4 -2\\
.6 2\\
1 0\\
};

\end{axis}


\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

And here is the undesired result, where the green area is plotted on top of the grid:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pgfplots` has its own set of layers so you can simply activate it with `set layers` and then use `on layer=axis background` for your green background; refer to section **4.28.2 Using Predefined Layers** and **4.28.3 Changing the Layer of Graphical Elements** of the manual for further information:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{0.8,1,0.8}%

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=8cm,
height=4cm,
xmajorgrids,
ymajorgrids,
set layers
]

% this should be behind the grid:
\addplot[fill=mycolor,draw=none,forget plot,on layer=axis background]
table[row sep=crcr]{
x y\\
0 -1 \\
1 -2 \\
1 1 \\
0 1 \\
};

% these should be in front of the grid
\addplot [color=black, line width=3pt]
table[row sep=crcr]{
0 0\\
.4 2\\
.6 1\\
1 1\\
};

\addplot [color=red, line width=3pt]
table[row sep=crcr]{
0 -1\\
.4 -2\\
.6 2\\
1 0\\
};

\end{axis}


\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I had to change `layer = axis background,` to `on layer = axis background,` (added `on`) to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest is to add `\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}` and then

```
% this should be behind the grid:

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\addplot[fill=mycolor,draw=none,forget plot]
table[row sep=crcr]{
x y\\
0 -1 \\
1 -2 \\
1 1 \\
0 1 \\
};
\end{scope}
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}

\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{0.8,1,0.8}%

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=8cm,
height=4cm,
xmajorgrids,
ymajorgrids,
% axis on top, % <-- uncomment to move all plots behind grid
]

% this should be behind the grid:
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\addplot[fill=mycolor,draw=none,forget plot]
table[row sep=crcr]{
x y\\
0 -1 \\
1 -2 \\
1 1 \\
0 1 \\
};
\end{scope}

% these should be in front of the grid
\addplot [color=black, line width=3pt]
table[row sep=crcr]{
0 0\\
.4 2\\
.6 1\\
1 1\\
};

\addplot [color=red, line width=3pt]
table[row sep=crcr]{
0 -1\\
.4 -2\\
.6 2\\
1 0\\
};

\end{axis}


\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

[image]