# set layers in PGFPLOTS polarplot not working as expected

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\begin{polaraxis}[xtick={0,90,180,270}, ytick={0,1}, ymax=1.5, xticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\si{\degree}}, set layers=default]
\addplot[thick,fill=gray,draw=none,opacity=0.5,  domain=0:360,
samples=360,]{1};
\addplot+[thick, mark=none, >->] table[col sep=comma,x=ang,y=abs] {images/tikz/stability/stable.csv};
\addplot+[thick, mark=none, >->, orange] table[col sep=comma,x=ang,y=abs] {images/tikz/stability/instable.csv};
\end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

It draws some plots to a polar plot. With the first plot I try to fill the inner of the unit circle. However, I have not succeeded in doing so. I want the circle to be behind the axis. For this, I tried *set layers* in the options of the axis environment.

The first problem I experience is that: set layers=defautl and set layers should have the same effect, according to the documentation, but they don't. With set layers (without default), the axes vanish. with default the axes stay.

With the key *on layer=axis background* I tried to move the first plot behind the axes, as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268328/how-to-move-a-single-plot-behind-the-grid).

This does not work because the layer is unknown. I then tried *set layers=standard*. With this setting, the layer name is known, but the axes disappear again.

Can someone tell me, how to draw a plot behind polar axes?

Thank you

EDIT:

I've created a mimimal (not) working example with three varieties of code. The first two images should create the same output but they don't. The last one doen't do anything.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\begin{polaraxis}[xtick={0,90,180,270}, ytick={0,1}, ymax=1.5, set 
layers=default]
\addplot[thick,fill=gray,draw=none,opacity=0.5,  domain=0:360,
samples=360,]{1};
\end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\begin{polaraxis}[xtick={0,90,180,270}, ytick={0,1}, ymax=1.5, set 
layers]
\addplot[thick,fill=gray,draw=none,opacity=0.5,  domain=0:360,
samples=360,]{1};
\end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\begin{polaraxis}[xtick={0,90,180,270}, ytick={0,1}, ymax=1.5, set 
layers=standard]
\addplot[thick,fill=gray,draw=none,opacity=0.5,  domain=0:360,
samples=360, on layer=axis background]{1};
\end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a complete MWE (and try `axis on top`). Nobody has `stable.csv`, so please also add a short csv file.

Comment: The code does the same thing without the two csv files. You can just comment these lines, but I will try to create a MWE.

Comment: If I comment out the two csv files, then the circle is on the background.

Comment: I want the circle to be behind the axis and the plots in front of the axis. But the documentation is wrong. axis on top helps, but in this case all plots are in front of the axis, which is not what I want.

Comment: Writing 'set layers' causes the axis to completely disappear. I only get the gray filled circle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now I can confirm your observation: the layers on polar plots do not work as expected. As a workaround, one can draw the grid by hand on the axis layer.

```
\documentclass[tikz,3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{polaraxis}[xtick={0,90,180,270}, ytick={0,1}, ymax=1.5,
xticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\si{\degree}},
 axis on top,grid style={draw=none}]
\addplot[thick,fill=red,draw=none,opacity=0.5,  domain=0:360,
samples=360,]{1};
% draw grid by hand
\begin{scope}[on layer=axis lines,thin,gray]
\draw(180,2) -- (0,2) (90,2) -- (270,2) (0,0);
\addplot[domain=0:360,samples=60,smooth]{1};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[on layer=axis foreground]
\addplot[thick,domain=0:360] {sin(x)};
\end{scope}
% \addplot+[thick, mark=none, >->] table[col sep=comma,x=ang,y=abs] {images/tikz/stability/stable.csv};
% \addplot+[thick, mark=none, >->, orange] table[col sep=comma,x=ang,y=abs] {images/tikz/stability/instable.csv};
\end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, the filled circle is on the background, i.e. behind the grid, but the plot is on the foreground.

Comment: It is a nice approach. However, the axis is still drawn in front of the two plots. Even with on layer=axis foreground. It does not work

Comment: @GNA You are right, there is indeed an issue. I looked through `tikzlibrarypgfplots.polar.code.tex` and did not find an obvious way to modify the grid drawing there, so the best thing I can offer is a workaround.

Comment: The best can't stay with a score of zero. +1.

Comment: @Sebastiano Mille grazie but this is not an answer by egreg. ;-)

Comment: @marmot With all my sincerity you will reach the skill of nr. 1 as egreg.

Comment: I'm fine with this solution. I just wantet to check if I'm just overseeing some trivial stuff. But it can't be helped. Something is wrong with the polar plot.

Comment: @GNA Yes, according to what I find, the layers do not work easily here (and I tried several things such as `every axis/.append style` and so on. Yet it might still be that there is a better solution. Let's see... ;-)